# The output of an adapter

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-request, terminology

I'm trying to name a function in a software package. Let's start with some backgrounds. The package provides supplemental functions to multiple upstream packages that train random forests. To avoid duplicated code, I use a function **A** to convert random forest objects from different upstream vendors into an intermediate object, and then have other functions **B1, B2, ...** operate on it. The name for **B**s have been decided, i.e. `featureContrib`, `trainsetBias`. However, I'm struggling to give **A** a good name.

I have come up with `intermediateRF`/`transtionalRF`/`transtionRF` ("RF" is a widely understood abbr. for "random forest", but them fail to capture **A**'s functionality to take objects of different types, and then convert them to something of a common structure. I would like to emphasis its [Polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)) nature in the name.

Other candidates include `middlewareRF`/`adapterRF`, but it seems to implies the resultant object is itself a middleware/adapter that can act on something else, instead of the output of a middleware/adapter. If I were to use this name, then **B**s need to be `featureContribCalculator` and `trainsetBiasCalculator` for consistency, which would be too verbose.

To sum up, what do you call the output of a middleware/adapter that takes different objects, and then convert them to intermediate objects with the same structure? It's fine to answer with a phrase, but please keep it no longer than 15 characters.

Comment: It's not clear whether you're looking for a name for A, or a name for the output objects of A. You say both at different times. Could you please clarify this?

Comment: @dwilli I'm naming **A**, but since I'm using the names of output objects as those of **B**s, it's preferable to use the names of output objects of **A** as its name, for the sake of consistency.

Comment: This seems to me a question more about electronics than the English language.

Comment: @WS2 It's software, actually. It's on the cusp of being appropriate here, but what's being asked for is an English term to use in naming a software widget that accurately captures the widget's function. So it does relate to English meaning and looking for the right word.

Comment: I’m closing this question because it doesn't appear to be about learning English.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, that type of a thing would normally be called factory - RFFactory, for instance. I don't think that's what you're aiming for, though.

Would 'StandardRF', 'CommonRF', 'ImplementedRF' or 'DerivedRF' work? Does this new object implement an interface? Could you call it 'IStandardRFProduct', or maybe just IRF?